# Why is the calculated cross-entropy not zero?

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

logits = torch.Tensor([0, 1])

counts = logits.exp()

probs = counts / counts.sum() # equivalent to softmax

loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, probs)
```

Here, `loss` is roughly equal to `0.5822`.

However, I would expect it to be `0`.

If I understand the docs correctly, [`torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html) can accept an array of logits and an array of probabilities as its input and target parameters, respectively (converted to `pytorch.Tensor`'s).

I believe `probs` to be the true distribution, and that `F.cross_entropy` therefore should return 0.

Why is `loss` not `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch treats your logits as outputs that it will first convert to probabilities by running them through a softmax:

```
p_log = torch.log(F.softmax(logits, dim=0))
torch.dot(p_log, probs)
```

tensor(0.5822)

Some discussion here - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-crossentropyloss-include-the-softmax-function/4420. I think the naming could be clearer, for example in tensorflow it is tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.

Comment: good discussion here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390842/cross-entropy-in-pytorch